# Group same QuerySet elements

Tags: python, django

I have a queryset that looks like this:

```
Order.objects.all()
<QuerySet [
         <Order: 2017-11-09 Apple 2 >, 
         <Order: 2017-11-09 Banana 1>, 
         <Order: 2017-11-09 Pears 2 >, 
         <Order: 2017-10-01 Berry 2>
]>
```

As you can see there are 3 orders with the same date.

How can I group this order by the date, so it will become something like this:

```
Order: 2017-11-09 Apple 2, Banana 1, Pears 2
Order: 2017-10-01 Berry 2
```

Comment: you can use the .distinct() to select the unique date instances. then use for-loop to traverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my solution:

1. First query orders, group them by date and fruit and aggregate quantities

   ```
   orders = Order.objects.values('date', 'fruit').annotate(total_order=Sum('quantity'))
   ```
2. Then further group results with `groupby` from `itertools`

   ```
   from itertools import groupby

   groups = {}
   for key, group in groupby(orders, key=lambda x:x['date']):
       groups[str(key)] = list(group)
   ```

The output of groups would look like this:

```
{
    '2017-11-09': [
        {'date': datetime.date(2017, 11, 9), 'fruit': 'banana', 'total_order': 1}, 
        {'date': datetime.date(2017, 11, 9), 'fruit': 'apple', 'total_order': 2}, 
        {'date': datetime.date(2017, 11, 9), 'fruit': 'pear', 'total_order': 2}
     ],
     '2017-10-01': [
        {'date': datetime.date(2017, 10, 9), 'fruit': 'berry', 'total_order': 2}, 
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Order.objects.all().order_by('date')`

'date' is the attribute which stores the date.

Comment: Thanks, but this will give the just ordered list, not grouped by date with elements. It should be like map or something. I dont know :/

Answer (score 0):

You must use the group by.but you can not show list order by date. you can for example count or average ... of order.

```
from django.db.models import Count
Order.objects.values('date').annotate(d_count=Count('date'))
```

and result:

```
[{'date': '2017-11-09', 'd_count': 3}, {'date': '2017-10-01', 'd_count': 1}]
```